# Prepare array of objects before passing it to Angularjs ng-repeat to avoid '10 $digest() iterations reached' error

Tags: angularjs

I have a following `ng-repeat` in my view:

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
  {{field.someValue}}
</div>
```

The content of `fields` needs to be `preprocessed` before it is given to the view. So in my controller I have a function that loops through the `fields` object and adds some keys and removes some keys. A simplified pseudocode would look like that

```
myApp.controller('FieldsController', function($scope) {
  $scope.fields = loadFieldsFromResource();
  var i=0;

 for(i = 0; i < $scope.fields.length; i++) {
   if ($scope.fields[i].someProperty > maxValue) {
     // Remove an item from the array
     $scope.fields.splice(i,1);
   } 
   else if ($scope.fields[i].someProperty < minValue) {
     // Add an item to the array
     $scope.fields.splice(i,0,createNewField());
   }
 }
})
```

Now this produces correct output but gives me the `10 $digest() iterations reached.` error. 
How can I make it work? (I **only need the preprocessing done on init**).

I've tried to copy the `fields` with `angular.copy()` to a temporary variable. Do the preprocessing on it and then assigning it to the `fields` variable but still I get the same error.

Is there a way of doing this sort of `preprocessing` outside of the Angular watch before I give it to the view?

Comment: I tried to make a fiddle and there is a logic error.  You are changing the array while you are looping through it.  You are adding values, which will cause the array to shift and it will keep growing. Also removing values causes it to shift down, skipping indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use ng-init?

```
<div ng-init="processFields()" ng-repeat="field in fields">
  {{field.someValue}}
</div>
```

And then in your controller you could do the following:

```
myApp.controller('FieldsController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.fields = [];

    $scope.processFields = function () {
        var fields = loadFieldsFromResource();
        var i = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            if (fields[i].someProperty > maxValue) {
                // Remove an item from the array
                fields.splice(i, 1);
            }
            else if (fields[i].someProperty < minValue) {
                // Add an item to the array
                fields.splice(i, 0, createNewField());
            }
        }

        $scope.fields = fields;
    }
})
```

I don't know your entire situation but I have few places where I need things loaded and sorted before I display.